# Ruby on Rails: Getting the value from a select form field before it's submitted

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the value of a select form field, before it's submitted and save the value into a variable. I know that you can't do it with Rails only. So JavaScript/Ajax will do the trick. I'm pretty new to Rails, so I hope you can help.

Comment: if you are submitting using a form, what is your purpose of saving it into a variable. You can save the value simply using jQuery or Javascript if you want to save it your DOM. If you want to save it in your database, you can access the values which are posted to your rails application from the form

Comment: @SudiptaMondal I want to catch & save the value into a variable, before the form gets submitted. This allows my form fields to respond dynamically (e.g. fade in new form fields, if the one before has value X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> before it's submitted and save the value into a variable

This is the realm of `jquery`/`javascript` -- *anything* on the client side is JS, not Rails.

Rails/Ruby is basically like PHP -- it runs on the server.

Although `@Sudipta Mondal`'s answer will help, you have to remember to *bind* your code to an event (typically *change*):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "select#form_item", function(e){
   $(this).attr("data-option-value", $(this).val()); // this sets the "data-option-value" to the value
});
```

Perhaps this isn't the context in which you intended; it should give you the ability to dynamically assign the relative value to the field.

Comment: I've saved your JavaScript into the application.js file. Now I want to fill in the data-option-value with the respective value. But I get a `undefined local variable or method field` error, when I try to do this `data-option-value="<%= field %>"` Any Ideas? Thank you

Comment: Where are you getting `<%= field %>` from?

Comment: I thought that `var field = $(this).val();` can be read by this?

Comment: `$(this)` is javascript, whereas `<%= field %>` is Rails - they won't work together as you need. If you explain a little more, I can give you more context

Comment: I just want to use the value of a form as it gets selected in the dropdown inside my Rails views before the form gets submitted.

Comment: Well my above code provides it. You get a *javascript* variable called `field`, with which you're able to do whatever you want. Which element are you using `data-option-value` for? - I'll give you some code to get it working if you want

Comment: @Rick Peck it's more or less connected to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262356/rails-form-fields-loops) question. I am trying to hand over a select-form field value, which allows my rails app to hide or show specific form fields.

Comment: Hmmm okay - do you have more context? Such as how do you want Rails to determine which forms to show -- through ajax or on the same form?

Comment: I use [this](https://github.com/vollnhals/dependent-fields-rails) gem. It's more or less JavaScript. I want to show select-form-fields only when a specific value gets selected from the select-form-field above. E.g. If i select Adidas (Model: Brand) then a second Select-form appears (Model: Groups) where I can choose between Shoes, Shirts, .. The Brand and the Model group have the same column (Brand), so I can connect them through the models.

Comment: Nice okay, this is making progress. So you just need to update the element to have `data-option-value` as the field value?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to manipulate the data-option-value to the value that was selected before and store this value in a global variable, so I can use it in another form field.

Comment: Global var? Why not just update the other field from the `.change` function?

Comment: Sorry. Hard to describe :). 
The value from the first select form should be saved in a global variable before the form gets submitted so I can access the value in my rails app. E.g. to use it in other select form attributes. It's a bit complicated and special. But it allows my app to show dependent form fields that are depending on the form field values from other form fields.

Comment: Exactly! That's what I need.

Comment: Okay, have you got the other actions set up or do you need me to suggest how to do those... otherwise I'll just give you some info on this functionality?

Comment: I haven't changed anything yet. Especially the suggestes JavaScript part seems very tricky if one want to use it with rails. Feel free to go ahead. I'm so glad that you're helping me with that!

Answer (score 2):

Using Javascript

```
var form_field_value = document.getElementById("pass-id").value
```

Using jQuery

```
var form_field_value = $("#pass-id").val()
```

Each of the above ways, will save the value in your DOM, so you can access it later. Do make sure, of the scope of the variables, when you are declaring them :)

Comment: Thank you. How would the code look like, if I want to save the output into a variable?

Comment: the variable in code above *form_field_value* is only going to store the data of your field. you can use it later in an if condition to display another form `if (form_field_value == "X") {//display new form}`

Comment: @Harakiri could you please mark my answer as accepted, if you are satisfied with the solution.